# interpreters in injection attacks

Tags: security, sql-injection, code-injection, interpreter

The OWASP definition of injection attacks says that -

> Injection flaws, such as SQL, OS, and LDAP injection occur when untrusted data is sent to an interpreter as part of a command or query. The attacker’s hostile data can trick the interpreter into executing unintended commands or accessing data without proper authorization.

What does interpreter means in each case (LDAP, OS, SQL etc)? Is an interpreter needed for all types of injection attacks such as XML, XPath, HTTP etc?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the nature of a code injection attack is that the attacker tricks the application into running some code statements that are not part of the intended functions of that application.

This means there has to be some mechanism to parse and execute the malicious code contained in the attacker's payload before the owner of the application can stop it.

In theory, an application could compile code and run it automatically, but it's much more common for this type of attack to use malicious code that is not compiled, but is interpreted at runtime.

Your other examples, XML, XPath, HTTP, are not typically associated with code injection.

- XML is not code, it's a data format.
- HTTP is not code, it's a protocol.
- XPath is sort of like code, but a very specialized type of code. It's an expression language to identify elements in an XML document. It's limited in what it can do, so it's not a common vector for code injection attacks.